# Add redirection in submission handler

Tags: redirection

How can I redirect users to a node in a form submission handler similarly to the following code?

In my form alter I have added an additional submit button:

```
$form['actions']['save_and_exit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save & Exit'),
    '#submit' => array('custom_submit'),
  );

function custom_submit(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface 
  $form_state) {
    $syst‌​em_path = '/node/2';
    $url = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($syst‌​em_path);
    $form_state->setRedirect($url);
}
```

Then I'm getting following error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route
>   "/mypage" does not exist. in
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 190 of
>   C:\wamp\www\www_assure_local_com\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider.php).

where `/mypage` is the url alias of my `/node/2`.

Comment: $form_state->setRedirectUrl

Answer (score 2):

A form submission handler never returns a `RedirectResponse` object to redirect users. (It actually doesn't return any value.)

A form submission handler calls [`FormState::setRedirect()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.4.x), or [`FormState::setRedirectUrl()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirectUrl/8.4.x) which accepts a [`Url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.4.x) object, for example the value returned from `Url::fromUri('//my_node_url_alias')`.

Comment: Sorry.. I'm not clear on that. how could I put it submit function? like this `$url = Url::fromUri('//my_node_url_alias'); FormState::setRedirectUrl($url);` ?

Comment: `$url = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($system_path, $langcode)`, where `$system_path` is `"/node/$nid"`

Comment: @Clive, I have updated my code in above question. Still it is not working. Throwing error like route not exists.

Comment: Read https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirectUrl/8.2.x and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!FormState.php/function/FormState%3A%3AsetRedirect/8.2.x, you need to use one of those with the correct parameters

Comment: @ARUN Use `$form_state->setRedirectUrl(Url::fromUri('//my_node_alias'))`.